# While taking wudu I wash my hair 3 times along with my ears

Tags: wudu

السلام عليكم ورحمة الله وبركاته.
While I take wudu I wipe my hair from the front to the back along with my ears 3times, I have researched it and they say do it only once, I did this technique even when doing ghusl, so now I am worried if I have been taking wudu wrong this whole time.
Please any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. I do assume you mean that you wipe over your head, as washing is not required for wudu'. I'm just a bit astonished that you do it along with your ears. This is the first time I hear this.

Comment: Yes sorry I mean wipe it with water not wash

Answer (score 1):

Your wudu will be valid as you have covered all the obligatory requirements, doing something extra does not invalidate the wudu.

Wiping the head three times is actually considered as a Sunnah by the Shafi'is based on the hadith:

> رأيت عثمان بن عفان غسل ذراعيه ثلاثا ثلاثا **ومسح رأسه ثلاثا** ثم قال رأيت رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم فعل هذا
>
> I saw ‘ Uthman b. ‘ Affan (perform ablution). He washed his forearms three times **and wiped his head thrice**. He then said : I saw the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) doing like that.
>
> <sup>— [Abu Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:110)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

The head and ears are to be wiped only once. Doing it 3 times would be haram so stay away from that but since you didn't know before, there is no sin or blame on you for that.

and Allah knows best

Ps: I said its Bidah but it is a sin only sorry

Comment: So can I wipe my hair and my ears at the same time while taking wudu

Comment: What do you mean, how would you do them simultaneously?